# Soap request with cookie php

Tags: php, cookies, soap-client

I am trying to generate a soap request. I need to authenticate to a 3rd party url (the authentication works well)but i experience an issue to store the login informations with cookie.
The error is the following  (url, username and password have been masked):

*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property SoapClient::$_cookies in C:\xampp\htdocs\result_xml.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\result_xml.php on line 21*

Below the code :

```
    // Login information
$soapClient = new SoapClient(
    'http://'url',
    array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
    'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
    'features' => SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE

    )
   );
$loginResponse = $soapClient->Login(
   array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password')
   
   );
$loginResult = $loginResponse->LoginResult;
$cookies = $soapClient->_cookies;

print_r($LoginResult);
```

Could you help me to find out where i am wrong ?

Thank you in advance